# How to remain state when page refresh in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I use react in the project. The modal closes when the user refreshes, but I want to modify it so that it doesn't close. I found 'beforeunload' event, but I want to prevent 'alert' from appearing.
And when I refresh, I want to keep the data I received from the API and maintain the model.
I want to make the modal close only when I press the close button, what methods can I use?

This is not a real code. Just a example...

```
function Modal() {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false)

  const handleOpen = () => {
    setOpen(!open);
  }

  return (
    <Modal>
      <button onClick={handleOpen}>
      modal
     </button>
     (some data from API)
    </Modal>
  )
}
```

Comment: If you want state to persist after refresh read about local storage

Comment: Thank you!! Is there a way not to use localStorage? I'm using redux, but I was wondering if there's a way to do it without using redux. I asked because I thought it would be possible to preserve the state by preventing the refresh.

Comment: When you refresh the page you need to use localStorage to persist the state. Unless what you really mean is that you have some data "in" the modal, and when you close it, the data needs to be loaded again?

Comment: It's a modal that tells you the news, so I have to get the data back when I close it and open it again. I couldn't clarify the question!

Answer (score 0):

Read localStorage value first, if it exists use it, and then everytime you set a new value update it in local storage as well.

- Remember localstorage only saves values as a `string`; and when it doesn't exist it will come back as a `null`.

```
function Modal() {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("open")) || false)

  const handleOpen = () => {
    setOpen((prevState) => {
      localStorage.setItem("open", !prevState);
      return !prevState;
    });
  }

  return (
    <Modal>
      <button onClick={handleOpen}>
      modal
     </button>
    </Modal>
  )
}
```

Comment: I have a similar issue. Do I need to save all the state on all my pages to localStorage ?

Comment: If you want to persist the state on refresh, then yeah. But you can create an object for state, and read the 1 localStorage value. (depends on your use case though)

Comment: Or google `useLocalStorage` hook, and use that instead of `useState` :)

Comment: Thank you for the useful answers. I am hosting my app in Netlify, I found the easy way around this was to add the _redirects file in my build folder. Netlify them handles all that